# Retrieving imported paths from the result of Babel.transform

Tags: babeljs

In the special (no-Node) project I'm currently working on, I use Babel 6 to transform JS-files to es2015. The result of the transform function returns an object, with a metadata property, which contains all imports the compiled file has as dependency. I use this to determine the files to load and their loading order.

Sadly in Babel 7 the metadata object was removed from the result and I don't see the required imports anywhere. In the [API-migration notes](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration-api) I find the following statement:

> Removed babel.metadata since the generated plugin metadata is always
>   included in the output result.

So what is meant with "output result" here? Where can I find the dependencies now? Or do I have to generate them myself with a plugin? If so, I would appreciate a pointer how to do this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Babel 6 and Babel 7 have the ability for plugins to add metadata information onto the object exposed in the plugin API as `file.metadata`, and to have that metadata available on the result returned from `babel.transform*()` APIs. That has not changed.

> Removed babel.metadata since the generated plugin metadata is always included in the output result.

refers to the fact that Babel 6 has an option that you could pass to Babel. If you passed `metadata: false`, the metadata collected by plugins would not be included in the result returned from `babel.transform*()`. The option was removed to make the results more consistent and because there wasn't an obvious reason to allow removing the metadata.

Babel 7 *did* remove Babel's logic to automatically populate the metadata with information about imports and exports, because it was not documented, not implemented consistently, and was not behavior that belonged in the core of Babel. If that is data that you want, you'll need to write and enable your own plugin to collect that data and set some field on `file.metadata`, so that you can access it alongside the transformation result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never doubted, that you had a reason for doing this. I will try to write a plugin, that restores this functionality for me.